# GPS location not accurate

Tags: google-maps, gps, location, nmea

I am using a GPS device to track my device location. The data was received in NMEA format and I parsed the latitude and longitude from the GPRMC data. But the issue is that the location obtained when checked in google maps was found to around 600 meters shifted from my actual location. On checking the GPS data obtained from my Smartphone GPS from the same location it was perfect. Why would this happen. Do I need to use some calculation after parsing or is this some issue with my GPS device (The device being used is MC-1612-G - from LOCOSYS Technology).

Comment: What is the data returned?  What do you expect it to be?

Comment: The value we are getting for latitude and longitude is LAT : 833.435500  and  LONG: 7653.529800, But the actual values are LAT : 833.466 and LONG : 7653.402

Comment: Those are not valid latitudes or longitudes (at least for a google map).

Comment: This is the data we receive in GPRMC format. We convert it into degree format for getting the proper latitude and longitude.

Comment: @geocodezip they aren't really valid NMEA sentence format, unless Anandhu is in Columbia/Venezuela, or off the coast of southern India as  Anandhu  did not specify +/- or N/S/E/W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue was with setting the datum value for my GPS module. The datum I was using was TOKYO Mean and i was plotting the co-ordinates in google map. That was the reason why a shift in location was found.

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy of your GPS module should be listed in the datasheet. Most of the GPS modules used for hobby purposes have an accuracy of less than +/-3 meters with the GPS module having a clear view of the sky and an HDOP of less than ~3 for the area. 

Although my answer would change depending on the consistency of the errors that you are getting, it seems like it is a GPS Glitch. 

I myself am having the same issue with the GPS module that I have on my quadcopter. 
You might want to checkout [this website](http://copter.ardupilot.com/wiki/configuration/gps-and-gcs-failsafes/gps-failsafe/) to see how the arducopter autopilot detects GPS glitches and how it recovers.

Comment: +/- 3 meters for off the shelf gps is optimistic. Check out the [`demo_gegps3.py`](https://github.com/wadda/gps3) to watch gps jitter on a static commercial grade gps.  It displays a gps track on Google Earth

Comment: The MediaTek MT3329 GPS V2.0 that costs about $40 has a position accuracy rating of < 3m. https://store.3drobotics.com/products/mediatek-mt3329-gps-v2-0

Comment: Yeah, that's a standard; <3 meters %50 of the time, 10 meters %95 of the time.  I'm just nit-picking that to say 3 meters is optimistic.

Comment: Oh I see. Any comments on how to fix these glitch issues in arducopters?

Comment: It's more a limitation of the hardware.  One nanosecond is 30cm., mix in environment distortion <3 meters %50 of the time is pretty good.  After my last comment, just for fun, I ran [`gpsprof`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1//gpsprof/) and it showed a cluster of 100 fixes within 0.21336 meters of each other (altitude 4.564 meters), phenomenally accurate, **but** *only to itself*.  Accuracy, and repeatability, to and in the *real* world is another matter.